# Why/how is OpenVPN tinkering with my BIND9 configuration?

Tags: linux, vpn, dns, openvpn

I have a DNS server that lacks forwarders.  Its only aim is to resolve machines on my internal domain.  As such, dig/ping somevaliddomain.com returns nothing.  This is the behavior I want.

When I start up OpenVPN on the server (successfully via IP, rather than \domain) and run the same dig/ping queries, my BIND9 server is automagically returning records/responses.  What is OpenVPN tinkering with and how can I stop it?

My OpenVPN configuration follows:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote [removed the IP address] 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca [removed the certification file]
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass password.txt # I realize this is bad practice.
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
```

Comment: Without forwarders *and* without root hints?

Comment: ...annnnd, I'm an idiot.  I would have noticed this immediately but I had also been tinkering with iptables, so it seemed as though the external resolution only occurred when OpenVPN was up.  Thanks for jostling my brain.